# My kafka consumer produces non sequential data

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My question is - under what circumstances would a kafka consumer receive non sequential data?

Answer (score 0):

Message ordering is guaranteed *within a partition only*. If your consumer is pulling data from multiple partitions then the messages may appear out of order.

Ref: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_guarantees

Answer (score 0):

Kafka serves a messaging bus & it guarantees the ordering of messages. This means that the order in which you committed message to the topic; consumer will poll the messages in the same order.

Now in your case, you need to check

- how producer is committing messages?
- how do you handle message retries ?
- and check consumer as suggested by @Robin Moffatt